# Invisible span is adding whitespace

Tags: html, css

I have a hidden span that holds an `ID` in my View so that I can keep track of information but it is adding whitespace and pushing my content over.

Is there anyway to remove this whitespace? This was normally not an issue until my ID number started to increase from single to double and then to triple digits in length, and now it makes an awkward extra space in front of some elements. I tried adding margin and padding tags to the style but nothing worked. :(

My span is

```
<span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID col-xs-0">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>
```

Example:
ID for Randy is 7 and the ID for Mel is 1026, this causes extra whitespace for Mel now and makes it look offset.

[image]

Note: I tested this theory out by removing the span and everything lined up correctly, so I am positive that the span is causing this.

Thank you!

Comment: `visibility: hidden` means the content is hidden, and hidden *only*. It is still part of the flow of document, and in particular will take up the space needed for its content (which will grow as the number does).

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/blfaqhidden.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `display: none` for the span?

Comment: Neato! Thanks!! I shall mark correct when timer expires.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="visibility:collapse"></span>
```

`hidden` is invisible but preserving space. Think of it as transparent.

`collapse` is invisible but no preservation of white space.

`display:none` should work, but then you will have to remember to change the display back to `inline` when you want to make it visible.